# Trying to draw 3d terrain using cocos2d-x 3.8.1

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I am trying to draw a solid grid in a 3d view in cocos2d-x

bool MeshTerrain::init(){

```
if(!Node::init()){

    return false;

}

positions.push_back(-5.0f);positions.push_back(-5.0f);positions.push_back(0.0f);
positions.push_back(5.0f);positions.push_back(-5.0f);positions.push_back(0.0f);
positions.push_back(5.0f);positions.push_back(5.0f);positions.push_back(0.0f);
positions.push_back(-5.0f);positions.push_back(5.0f);positions.push_back(0.0f);

texs.push_back(0.0f);texs.push_back(0.0f);
texs.push_back(1.0f);texs.push_back(0.0f);
texs.push_back(1.0f);texs.push_back(1.0f);
texs.push_back(0.0f);texs.push_back(1.0f);

indices.push_back(0);
indices.push_back(1);
indices.push_back(2);

indices.push_back(0);
indices.push_back(2);
indices.push_back(3);


mesh = cocos2d::Mesh::create(positions, normals, texs, indices);
mesh->setTexture("texture.png");

return true;
```

}

void MeshTerrain::draw(cocos2d::Renderer *renderer, const cocos2d::Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags){

```
auto programstate = mesh->getGLProgramState();
auto& meshCommand = mesh->getMeshCommand();
GLuint textureID = mesh->getTexture() ? mesh->getTexture()->getName() : 0;

meshCommand.init(_globalZOrder
      , textureID
      , programstate
      , 0
      , mesh->getVertexBuffer()
      , mesh->getIndexBuffer()
      , mesh->getPrimitiveType()
      , mesh->getIndexFormat()
      , mesh->getIndexCount()
      , transform
      ,flags);

renderer->addCommand(&meshCommand);
```

}

But I am keep geting the same error:

Assert failed: GLProgramState cannot be nill
Assertion failed: (glProgramState), function init, file /Users/Juggernogger93/Desktop/StormStrike/StormStrike/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCMeshCommand.cpp, line 108.

Is there any one that knows how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `getGLProgramState()`, not 0.